# C++ modules behind the scenes

Tags: c++

Reading "A Tour of C++" I reached "modules" and that they should be used instead of including a header.

1. > A module is compiled only once   (rather than in each translation unit in which it is used)
2. > if you #include header.h 101 times, the text of header.h will be processed by the compiler 101 times

Maybe I am missunderstanding but lets go through a simple example

```
      src1.cpp includes header.h
      src2.cpp includes header.h
```

The text of header.h is copied by the compiler into each src file? Then each source produces an object file which are then linked into .exe

How does it work with a module? Is it dynamically linked to the program and hence only one copy is present and processed?

Comment: To find out more, look at how Pascal does it as Pascal modules are a source of great inspiration here.

Comment: There is not yet an agreed standard for modules. How they will work out, if indeed they do, is not yet clear. My personal feeling is that they won't work out well, because they seem to be remarkably similar to how templates were handled in Cfront, which was not a good thing.

Comment: Minor nit - "The text of header.h is copied by" the pre-processor (not the compiler) " into each"  compilation unit (not src file).   By your invocation of the compiler command (i.e. g++): a) The source files are unchanged. b) The header files are unchanged.  c) The preprocessor creates a "compilation unit".  c) The compilation unit is submitted to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is substantial because with current approach everything is done on copy-and-paste approach to the whole problem.

Includes are verbatim copied into other files and then processed altogether. The same code processed in each translation unit as many times as needed.

What's going to happen with modules is that you'll have a specific import directive which will map to a module which already exposes a precise API and has a specific binary file which is linked to the final executable.

You won't need an header file which exposes that API because the source will be analyzed and a "interface file" will be automatically generated which enumerates all exported symbols that will be available to importers of that module.

Mind that this is just some generic approach since the precise definition is yet to be standardized.